# Get Query Params on route, Angular Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, query-string

Is it possible to get the query params server side?
I have Lambda Cloudfront deployed version of my Angular application.

When the platform browser takes place everything works nice.

When I try to get the query params server-side I always get null/undefined.

I have tried this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.queryId = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id');
  this.metaPlatform.addTag({ property: this.queryId, content: this.queryId });
}
//I get this meta tag:
<meta property="null" content="null">
```

And also tried this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
    this.meta.addTag({property: snapshot.url.split('=')[1],content: snapshot.url.split('=')[1]);
}
//I get this meta tag:
<meta property="undefined" content="undefined">
```

I would like to set meta tags based on the queryParams but I can't find a way to have them server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like CloudFront configuration issue.

In CloudFront created Behavior check if "Query String Forwarding and Caching" is configured to forward specific or all parameters.